# How to Uploading my files to a webserver?

Tags: webserver

I uploaded my files to the webserver hostgator, using cyberduck. all the files uploaded. But one of my html pages and its scss file could not be found. The scss files got converted to css so  that's not the issue. I tried reloading them but the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

To specif files you can get upload the file through cPanel's File Manager

How to Upload a File Using File Manager

To upload a file through cPanel's File Manager, please do the following:

1 Login to cPanel.

2 Under Files, click File Manager.

3 Select Web Root and Show Hidden Files, then click Go.

4 Click to open the folder to which you'd like to upload files.

5 Click Upload from the top toolbar.

6 Click Browse (some web browsers will have Choose File instead).

7 Select the file on your computer that you wish to upload.

8 Once the file has been selected, it will automatically upload. You may select additional files while uploads are in progress.

more detailed information: https://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-upload-a-file-using-the-file-manager